# XSLT to XML - how to convert attributes to tags and num tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert this XML file to standard XML with tags like `<id>1</id>`

XML original file   code:

```
 <Products>
<!-- FIRST PART -->
    <Product id="ADEBLDADE0001" name="Black  Decker BL4018 Battery" producer="BLD" categoryId="ADE-ADE" warranty="F012M" priceNet="43.95" vat="23" vat_type="zwykły" pkwiu="27.20.23.0" externalWarehouse="N" available="30" date="2017-03-13" onOrder="N" specialOffer="N" lastChange="2022-10-17" smallPallet="N" productIsLarge="N" reported="T" EAN="5035048560044" manufacturerPartNumber="BL4018-XJ" sizeWidth="80" sizeLength="130" sizeHeight="110" weight="690" sizeMeasurementUnit="mm" weightMeasurementUnit="g" dimensionalWeight="228" additionalAvailabilityInfo="" expiryDate="1900-01-01" ETA="" incomingStock="0" mainCategoryTree="House and Garden" categoryTree="Tools - accessories" subCategoryTree="Batteries">
<!-- SECOND PART -->
    <Images>
    <Image url="/Icecat/O2N59732L0C0C1V6o7K4N143m7O7K7A8.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
    <Image url="/Icecat/I4B7m9t9K000X1b6w7V471A3H7R737c8.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
    <Image url="/Icecat/O9P0t7g7k0k0E1s6H7O4u1R3H7c757V9.jpg" isMain="1" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
    <Image url="/Icecat/I1P2w3a2c0r0N116X7E4P1a3n7l7w7q9.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
    <Image url="/Icecat/T9X096A3D0D0T1d6A7h481i3B7P7A8L0.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
    <Image url="/Icecat/Q1D233T3K020Z10607c421L3N7Z7Q8n1.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
    <Image url="/Icecat/Z2X2z2e5s03031B6G7r4j1Z2W4C9B926.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
    </Images>
<!-- THIRD PART -->
    <Multimedia/>
    <TechnicalSpecification>
    <Section name="Features">
    <Attributes>
    <Attribute name="Product type">
    <Values>
    <Value Name="Battery"/>
    </Values>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Battery technology">
    <Values>
    <Value Name="Lithium-Ion (Li-Ion)"/>
    </Values>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Battery capacity">
    <Values>
    <Value Name="2 Ah"/>
    </Values>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Battery voltage">
    <Values>
    <Value Name="18 V"/>
    </Values>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Product colour">
    <Values>
    <Value Name="Grey"/>
    <Value Name="Black"/>
    <Value Name="Orange"/>
    </Values>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Number of batteries included">
    <Values>
    <Value Name="1 pc(s)"/>
    </Values>
    </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    </Section>
    </TechnicalSpecification>
    </Product>
    </Products>
```

Except result similar to:

```
<Products>
<product>
    <id>ADEBLDADE0001</id>
    <name>Black  Decker BL4018 Battery</name>
    <producer>BLD</producer>
    <categoryId>ADE-ADE</categoryId>
    <warranty>F012M</warranty> 
    <priceNet>43.95</priceNet> 
    <vat>23</vat> 
    <vat_type>zwykły</vat_type> 
    <pkwiu>27.20.23.0</pkwiu> 
    <externalWarehouse>="N"</externalWarehouse> 
    <available>30</available> 
    <date>2017-03-13</date>
     <onOrder>N</onOrder> 
    <specialOffer>N</specialOffer>
     <lastChange>2022-10-17</lastChange> 
     <smallPallet>N</smallPallet>
     <productIsLarge>N</productIsLarge>
     <reported>T</reported> 
     <EAN>5035048560044</EAN> 
     <manufacturerPartNumber>BL4018-XJ</manufacturerPartNumber>
     <sizeWidth>80</sizeWidth>
     <sizeLength>130</sizeLength>
     <sizeHeight>110</sizeHeight>
     <weight>690</weight>
     <sizeMeasurementUnit>mm</sizeMeasurementUnit>
     <weightMeasurementUnit>g"</weightMeasurementUnit>
     <dimensionalWeight>228</dimensionalWeight>
     <additionalAvailabilityInfo> </additionalAvailabilityInfo>
     <expiryDate>1900-01-01</expiryDate>
     <ETA></ETA>
     <incomingStock>0 </incomingStock>
     <mainCategoryTree>House and Garden </mainCategoryTree>
     <categoryTree>Tools - accessories </categoryTree>
     <subCategoryTree>Batteries></subCategoryTree>
    <Image_main>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_main>
    <Image_extra_1>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_1>
    <Image_extra_2>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_2>
    <Image_extra_3>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_3>
    <Image_extra_4>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_4>
    <Image_extra_5>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_5>
    <Image_extra_6>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_6>
    <Product_type>Battery</Product_type>
    <Battery_technology>Lithium-Ion (Li-Ion)</Battery_technology>
    <Battery_capacity>2 Ah</Battery_capacity>
    <Battery_voltage>18 V</Battery_voltage>
    <Product_colour>Grey Black Orange</Product_colour>
    <Number_of_batteries_included>1 pc(s)</Number_of_batteries_included>
    </Product>
    </Products>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Products">
        
<xsl:for-each select="Product">
    <Product>
<!-- FIRST PART - (THIS PART WORKING CORRECT)-->
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>

<!-- SECOND PART -->
                <xsl:for-each select="Images/image">
                    <xsl:element name="image{position()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
        
     <!-- THIRD PART START HERE -->
        
    </Product>
</xsl:for-each>
            
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now current output for above code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Product>
    <id>ADEDEWADE0009</id>
    <name>Akumulator DeWalt XR DCB184-XJ (Li-Ion)</name>
    <producer>DEW</producer>
<categoryId>ADE-ADE</categoryId>
<warranty>F012M</warranty>
<priceNet>234.00</priceNet>
<vat>23</vat>
<vat_type>zwykły</vat_type>
<pkwiu>27.20.23.0</pkwiu>
<externalWarehouse>N</externalWarehouse>
<available>30</available>
<date>2018-06-08</date>
<onOrder>N</onOrder>
<specialOffer>N</specialOffer><smallPallet>N</smallPallet><productIsLarge>N</productIsLarge><reported>T</reported><EAN>5035048466933</EAN><manufacturerPartNumber>DCB184-XJ</manufacturerPartNumber><sizeWidth>90</sizeWidth><sizeLength>75</sizeLength><sizeHeight>130</sizeHeight><weight>672</weight><sizeMeasurementUnit>mm</sizeMeasurementUnit><weightMeasurementUnit>g</weightMeasurementUnit><dimensionalWeight>175</dimensionalWeight><additionalAvailabilityInfo/><expiryDate>1900-01-01</expiryDate><ETA/><incomingStock>0</incomingStock><mainCategoryTree>Dom, Warsztat i Ogród</mainCategoryTree><categoryTree>Narzędzia - osprzęt</categoryTree><subCategoryTree>Akumulatory</subCategoryTree>
<image1/>
</Product>
```

Part1 working correct, but for part 2 I get only tag `<image1/>`. For the third part code, im not sure how to start.

Can someone help me convert the second part to create links to photos in numbered tags and for the third part convert this attributes with values to tags?

Comment: @michael.hor257k can you look on this please. Thank you.

Comment: They are called elements, not tags (an element generally has a start tag and an end tag), and your input is just as much "standard" as your desired output. Use of id attributes in particular is probably more "standard" than id elements, because it's directly supported by DTDs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also new to XSLT but the following statements should work:

```xml
<!-- SECOND PART -->

<xsl:for-each select=".//Image">
    <xsl:sort select="@isMain" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@isMain = 1">
            <Image_main>
                <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
            </Image_main>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{concat('Image_extra_',position())}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

```xml
<!-- THIRD PART -->

<xsl:for-each select=".//Attribute">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(@name,' ','_')}">
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="string-join(.//Value/@Name,' ')"/>-->
        <xsl:for-each select=".//Value/@Name">
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You should note that `string-join()` is only available in XSLT 2.0 or above. The OP's original stylesheet is version 1.0, so they may not be able to use this exact solution.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHaley, I didn't verify if `string-join()` was available in XPath 1.0. I fixed it now

Comment: One other thing mine had for the second part was an xsl:sort to move the `Image_main` before the "extra's". (See here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyygmEb)

Comment: @DanielHaley Is `fn:sort` available in XPath 1.0?

Comment: Not the xpath/xquery function sort; the element xsl:sort. (line 16 in the stylesheet in the fiddle I linked to)

Comment: @DanielHaley Ok, then I'll go check on how to use it

Comment: While this solution is valid and produces the proper output, I would think it would be better to take advantage of the way XSLT is built and use templates instead of for-each or even nest for-each.

Comment: @Sebastien I'm not familiar with XSLT at all so for me it's easier to write the code the same way as I would with pure XPath 3.1. From what I understand of your solution, you'll be testing the `match` condition of all the `xsl:templates` each time that you call `xsl:apply-templates`. While it's certainly neat, it seems a little wasteful; would it be possible to "apply" a specific template?

Comment: @Fravadona I agree that the template model can be hard to understand at first but it is very powerful. Yes named templates can be used. There are many good resources to understand the XSLT processing model. Example : https://lenzconsulting.com/how-xslt-works/

Answer (score 1):

This transformation applied to your input gives the required output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Products">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Product"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Product">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
          <xsl:element name="{name()}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Images/Image"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TechnicalSpecification/Section/Attributes/Attribute"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Image[@isMain='1']">
      <Image_main>
        <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
      </Image_main>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Image[@isMain='0']">
      <xsl:element name="{concat('Image_extra_',position())}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Attribute">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(@name,' ','_')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value/@Name"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcBdB9

Comment: Since this is XSLT 1.0, your `<xsl:value-of select="Values/Value/@Name"/>` is only getting the first `Value/@Name`. See `Product_colour` in your output for an example.